# Export Thunderbird adaptive junkmail filter data

Tags: spam-prevention, thunderbird, email-spam

Is there really no way to export/import the adaptive junk filter training between computers?

I just setup thunderbird on a new computer and I feel like the junk filtering is sorely lacking behind my other workstation where the adaptive junk filter has had quite some time to train. I can't find anything on it in the options or while googling.

Thanks in advance

Some links:

- [How the junk filtering works (bayesian filtering)](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Junk_Mail_Controls)
- [Junk Mail Controls feature description (old as mold)](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/mailnews/specs/spam/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to transfer this data by copying the file `training.dat` from your old [profile](https://mzl.la/2cYKHaB) to your new one.

Be sure to close both instances and backup your Profile folders before copying files from one profile to another.

You can also see [Mozilla Support](https://mzl.la/2cYKHaB#w_how-to-find-your-profile) on how to find your Profile folder and [Mozilla Zine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Files_and_folders_in_the_profile_-_Thunderbird) for a full list of files in your Profile folder.